# How to set each word on a new line?

Tags: java

How can I set each word of the inputted string onto a new line and place the output within an ASCII box?

I have the following code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class labSix {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter a line of text: ");
    String line = in.nextLine();

    printBox(line);

}

// Returns the length of the longest token in the line. 
private static int getMaxLength(String... strings) {
    int len = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (String str : strings) {
        len = Math.max(str.length(), len);
    }
    return len;
}

// Pad the strings with spaces.
private static String padString(String str, int len) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
    return sb.append(fill(' ', len - str.length())).toString();
}

// Fill the string to the amount determined in padString.
private static String fill(char ch, int len) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        sb.append(ch);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}


// Print the box
public static void printBox(String... strings) {
    int maxBoxWidth = getMaxLength(strings);
    String line = "+" + fill('-', maxBoxWidth + 2) + "+";
    System.out.println(line);
    for (String str : strings) {
        System.out.printf("| %s |%n", padString(str, maxBoxWidth));
    }
    System.out.println(line);
}


}
```

If I try to split the string and replace " " with "\n" then there is only a "|" added to the first and last lines.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your call to `printBox`. You currently pass one `String` named `line`, instead pass an array of `String`(s) by splitting the line on space. Like,

```
printBox(line.split(" "));
```

With just that change, when I input "Hello world Goodbye world" I get

```
+---------+
| Hello   |
| world   |
| Goodbye |
| world   |
+---------+
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much for your help. My rep isn't showing as I am under 15 but your post solved my question.

Answer (score 1):

The printBox function only receive one String with the total text, not the array as expected. You can change it to receive an array and split the received text to pass to the function, like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabSix {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Enter a line of text: ");
      String line = in.nextLine();

      printBox(line.split(" "));

  }

  // Returns the length of the longest token in the line. 
  private static int getMaxLength(String... strings) {
      int len = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
      for (String str : strings) {
          len = Math.max(str.length(), len);
      }
      return len;
  }

  // Pad the strings with spaces.
  private static String padString(String str, int len) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
      return sb.append(fill(' ', len - str.length())).toString();
  }

  // Fill the string to the amount determined in padString.
  private static String fill(char ch, int len) {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
      for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          sb.append(ch);
      }
      return sb.toString();
  }


  // Print the box
  public static void printBox(String[] strings) {
      int maxBoxWidth = getMaxLength(strings);
      String line = "+" + fill('-', maxBoxWidth + 2) + "+";
      System.out.println(line);
      for (String str : strings) {
          System.out.printf("| %s |%n", padString(str, maxBoxWidth));
      }
      System.out.println(line);
  }
}
```

And the result will be like this:

```
Enter a line of text: test longertest
+------------+
| test       |
| longertest |
+------------+
```

Comment: That solution worked perfectly. Thank you for the response.